# SQL password issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `database.cfg` file containing:

```
dbDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dbUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
dbUser=admin
dbPasswd=ascd
```

So, consider another file named `create.sql`, containing:

```
use mysql;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
--
--
-- DE1284: whc - the line with IDENTIFIED BY is used during install to get the default password
--
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost'
      IDENTIFIED BY 'abcd';
/* note: here "abcd " is password and same as in database.cfg and same as dbPasswd=ascd.
--
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%'
      IDENTIFIED BY 'abcd';
/* note: here "abcd " is password and same as in database.cfg and same as dbPasswd=ascd.
--
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS metric;
CREATE DATABASE metric;

USE metric;
```

So now in this file named "create.sql", instead of using password "abcd" how can I call this password from the file "Database.cfg". I need some help.

Comment: These are two different language files. The first one is a config for a display language using the ConfigIni syntax. The second is a pure MySQL query - MySQL will only execute pure SQL commands. You can look at the `source` command, but the file has to be modified. 
By the way, the First `GRANT` is overridden with the second `GRANT`

Comment: Is this mysql or MS SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tags as this looks like a MySQL question. The two products are unrelated.

Comment: yes , it is mysql .

Comment: So is there any possible way in which we can achieve this .@JeffreyVanLaethem And @tadman

Comment: A SQL file is just text, it can't do that. A simple wrapper script could do this though. Pick your scripting language and execute that `GRANT` command. There is no MySQL command-line tool for updating users, unlike other platforms such as Postgres which do.